# Excerpt using Read More Tag

Tags: excerpt, read-more

How do I get the excerpt of a post that is using a Read More Tag? [The documentation states](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/#comparison-with-the-more-quicktag) that I should use the `the_content` function, but I don't want that. I just want the text. Furthermore, I don't want the Read More link automatically inserted into the same `paragraph` tag - I just want the text, and I'll create my own Read More link. Essentially, I'm trying to print the excerpt of a post without the read more link. Can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the first argument of `the_content()` to an empty string:

```
<?php the_content( '' ); ?>
```

If you don't pass an argument it will use the default, which is a link with the text "(more…)", but by passing an empty string, the empty string (i.e. nothing) gets displayed instead.

If you want it in a variable, use `get_the_content( '' )` in the same way, but for formatting to match properly you'll need to apply the `the_content` filter:

```
$excerpt = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content( '' ) );
```

Comment: Can I not put that in a variable to use elsewhere?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: ah, I see.. thanks. I've accepted the answer. but don't have enough reputation points to have it show.